# How to get PackageInfo from DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to get package info into a DialogFragment to use some of the data in the OnClickListener but I am having a little bit of trouble.  Getting "Cannot resolve getPackageName()"

The following line is where I am having trouble at this.getPackageName()

```
final PackageInfo packageInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        final String packageName = getArguments().getString("packageName");

        final PackageInfo packageInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        final long lastVersionCode = prefs.getLong(LAST_VERSION_CODE_KEY, 0);
        final String title = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " v" + packageInfo.versionName;

        AlertDialog.Builder b=  new  AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton("Got it!",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                                // Mark this version as read
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                                editor.putLong(LAST_VERSION_CODE_KEY, packageInfo.versionCode);
                                editor.commit();
                                dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                );

        LayoutInflater i = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View v = i.inflate(R.layout.whatsnew,null);

        b.setView(v);
        return b.create();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

`getActivity().getPackageName()`

instead of

`this.getPackageName()`